# Eliminating/minimizing distortion in 200 NM EEZ buffers?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, buffer

I frequently need to calculate buffers of 200 nautical miles from country or baseline polygons in order to map maritime Exclusive Economic Zones (EEZs). However, I've noticed that when generating the buffers in QGIS, I get different results depending on the projection specs of the layer I'm buffering from. For example, in a recent project I'm using an azimuthal equidistant projection, and the buffer turns out differently depending on where the projection is centered. This also means that even if I center the projection on the country, there is often still significant distortion at more distant corners of the same country.

Is there any way to generate buffers without any distortion (i.e. equidistant from each node on the polygon from which they're being calculated)?